# Is it possible to re-mount a component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a top level component that's sending the updated `props` down to all child components.

One of the child components gets rendered like this in a `View` component like this:

```
const View = ({
  currentSection
}) => {
  console.log(currentSection.Component)
  return (
    <div>
      <div className='main-content'>
        <div className='sidenav'>
          <div className='section'>
            <h2 className='section-header'>My Login Page</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          { currentSection.Component }
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

`currentSection` is one of items in a list of components that gets passed down to the `View` when ever one of the list items is clicked.

Logging the `currentSection` yields something like this:

`{Component: {…}, id: "members", label: "Members"}`

Here's an example of one of the components in the list:

```
class Members extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      members: props.members
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { members } = this.state;

    return <MembersList members={members} />;
  }
}
```

You can see its a simple component but the strange issue is `props` are getting updated but the state isn't.

So basically component isn't re-mounting. It only mounts when everything gets server rendered for the first time.

So, is there any way I can re-mount it?

Comment: I did try to use `componentWillMount` & `componentDidMount` but they never get called.

Comment: Why do you need to put props into state? Why not call directly this.props.members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From React [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) about constructor() behavior:

> Note
>
> Avoid copying props into state! This is a common mistake:

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 // Don't do this!
 this.state = { color: props.color };
}
```

> The problem is that it’s both unnecessary (you can use
>   this.props.color directly instead), and creates bugs **(updates to the
>   color prop won’t be reflected in the state)**.
>
> **Only use this pattern if you intentionally want to ignore prop
>   updates**. In that case, it makes sense to rename the prop to be called
>   initialColor or defaultColor. You can then force a component to
>   “reset” its internal state by changing its key when necessary.
>
> Read our blog post on avoiding derived state to learn about what to do
>   if you think you need some state to depend on the props.

Comment: You know this made me think that I don't really need the `members` in the state.

Answer (score 0):

You may need `componentWillRecieveProps` lifecycle method or static method `getDerivedStateFromProps` in react 16.3+

Comment: Hmm, I tried to use `getDerivedStateFromProps` & tried to log `nextProps`, but it didn't log anything :( I am using `16.4.0` btw.

Comment: Umm, its quite a big application so I am not sure I can post a demo.

Comment: I think you can have individual demo to focus on the problems tracking, it should be much easier to finger it out.